# how to check if it is false positive - virustotal

Tags: virus

I have downloaded the program zarXsetup from http://www.z-a-recovery.com and run a virustotal scan.

The check shows "Rising have found    Malware.Heuristic!ET#88% (cloud:T7NHek7jVBJ) "
https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/f5e1943a1ad6d7fdad039ced4a1224bea7406d212b5fe510320d78792f793504/analysis/1500150371/

How do I check whether or not this is a false positive?

Comment: When a single engine detect something it's a false positive.  When that single engine is an engine that nobody actually uses then you know for a fact it's a false positive.

Comment: @Ramhound Furthermore, Rising is hard to work with. I reported a false positive six weeks to Rising and got no response.